# SQL Server Geography Query - only slow on remote server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm running the following query which takes around 1 whole second to execute against 25k records

```
DECLARE @p GEOGRAPHY = GEOGRAPHY::Point('54.8175053','-2.03567480000003',4326)

SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE geoData.STDistance(@p) < 10000
```

On my remote server, this takes 6-9 seconds.

My I/O speed is faster than my computer, also no resources are being maxed and this is the only query running.

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 on both machines.

Could this be a configuration issue? I've noticed that re-running the query doesn't seem to cache anything (takes the exact same amount of time)

Thanks

Comment: Am I missing something here - how is `geoData` related to `myTable`. it looks like you put something in the `where` clause that is not related the the table values at all.

Comment: Hi, geoData is the name of my geography column within mytable.

Comment: Can it be a data issue?   ie:  The table on remote server has more records to search through?

Comment: Hi, sadly not; my remote server db is an exact copy of my local database

Comment: You definitely have spatial indexes on both servers? How many of those 25k records are actually within 10,000m?

Comment: What happens if you run select count(*) instead of select * from ...?

Comment: Hi John, yep they're both geography columns if that's what you mean. The select count(*) takes the same time, average records return is 5-20, thanks for your help!

Comment: Are the actual query plans the same on each server? Check estimated v actual row counts for each operator (there won't be many since this is a pretty simple query).